# Full list of genres used in soundcloud api

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

Can anyone help me out by providing a list of all the "genres" that work with the soundcloud api?

I presumed by going to soundcloud.com/tags/$genre you could get the correct genre to use in the api but the results dont match.

So if anyone has any information on this would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no such thing as 'list of genres' on soundcloud, since every author can put whatever he wants for genre.

if you go by tags, maybe that's a better idea.
check this link on next.soundcloud: https://soundcloud.com/explore/tags

and this one http://soundcloud.com/tags on classic soundcloud (this one is not working right now, but in past, there was a list most recent/used tags.

- update: here on right are some popular tags: http://soundcloud.com/tracks